# Protecting Virtualized SSIS and SSRS servers

Tags: backup, ssis, ssrs, virtualisation, ssis-2014

I have a stand alone instance of SSIS and SSRS running on 2 seperate VM's in production. And I want to know if the Servers can be protected with some kind of Snapshot method like Veeam to restore them back in case they blow up. Please let me know if something like this is possible at all.

Comment: What virtal server platform are you using? VMware? Hyper-V?

Comment: They are hosted on Vmware

Comment: If you have access to the vcentre console you can easily create scheduled snapshots of the VM's. I have found them to be super reliable for all my SQL, SSIS and SSRS instances.

Comment: Okay. Can I restore the entire vm along with the servers with veeam along with the encryption keys for ssrs ?

Comment: The snapshot holds everything on the VM within the snapshot. The VM will be restored exactly as it is taken. Remember to quiesce memory when taking snapshots with VMWare to ensure memory cache's are flushed to disk and to avoid any corruption.

Answer (score 1):

We are using Veeam to backup our sql db, ssis and ssrs servers.  We are using native storage snapshot integration, which makes them happen faster.  Still we have some issues when running a snapshot when an SSIS package is running.  I would advise avoiding running snapshots during your SSIS package runs.

SSIS and SSRS encryption keys are stored on the machine and don't rely on any externals, so a restore of an entire machine will not require an additional key restore, although it is a good idea to back up your keys in case you have to rebuild and manually restore a machine for some reason.

We still run sql backups of all of our databases including ssis catalog to a network share.  We are planning to use Veaam for those 'application level' backups in the future.